# Geometric interpretation of tilted parabola locus

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$$ (x \,\cos \alpha + y \, \sin \alpha - p)^2= (x - x_f)^2 + (y - y_f)^2 $$

Can we get a geometrical interpretation of how pedal length of straight line and focus circle center $ (x_f,y_f)$  and circle radius are related, resulting in the above parabola locus?

EDIT1:

$$ e^2 (x \,\cos \alpha + y \, \sin \alpha - p)^2= (x - x_f)^2 + (y - y_f)^2 $$

can be for other conics directly by definition.

EDIT 2:

Main motivation is to get equation of the parabola/ conic with known  tilt angle (axis  inclined ) to include $xy$ term.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a parabola as a locus? In your equation above, the bracketed line is the directrix and the centre of your circle is the focus.

Comment: This formula you offered is not general enough. It doesn't cover $2y=x^2-1$

Comment: @David Quinn Ok got it .. for point away from origin. Please give the same in answer . We can multiply by e^2 for other conics.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov Put $ e=1, p=1, \alpha=\pi/2, x_f=y_f= 0 $

Comment: @Narasimham As I remember there was another formula, I think it didn't include p. You made an edit so my comment doesn't stand any more ;)

Comment: After David's comment  corrected some earlier error, unable to recall it just now, .. but apologies anyway. Also generalized the eccentricity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part X=xcosα+ysinα is rotation by angle α, so you always measure distance along a new "axis" X (if α=90 then X=x), and the RHS is just distance from a point.

[image]